# It is possible to add more contact numbers for a single persion from app in iphone?

Tags: iphone, contacts, addressbook

It is possible to add multiple contact numbers to a single person from iPhone app. And how can i retrieve the group contacts from iPhone address book. Any sample code/tutorial available for this? Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you search on SO or google?

Comment: Thanks for response. I have search my level best in Google. I found the answer to add a single contact to address book. But, i want to add multiple contact numbers for a single name. And also i need to retrieve group of contacts from address book. Is this possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is Possible, you can add multiple contact numbers for same Person/Contact like this

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumberMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABPersonPhoneProperty);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumberMultiValue, @"11111111", kABHomeLabel, nil);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumberMultiValue, @"987654321", kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, nil);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumberMultiValue, @"1234567", kABWorkLabel, nil);
ABRecordSetValue(contactPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumberMultiValue, nil);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one more doubt. How can i edit and deleted an existing contact from iphone app? Can you please help me? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/62069-possible-delete-contacts-records-using-abaddressbook.html hope this link will work for you, do tell me reponse

Comment: Thank you Shahab Qureshi. I want your help in future. Thanks for your great help.